# VueJS Unit testing - I cannot run my tests. "Command 'test/unit' does not exists"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, npm, vuejs3

I'm trying to setup Unit Tests with VueJS 3. Reading [the docs of Vue 3](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/#what-next), I Installed test-utils 2.0

My package.json file looks like this :

```
{
  "name": "testsUnitVue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {

    ...

    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",

    ...

  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {

    ...

    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.21",

    ...

  }
}
```

I try to run my the tests with:

```
npm run test:unit
```

But I've the following error message:

```
> testsUnitVue@0.1.0 test:unit
> vue-cli-service test:unit

 ERROR  command "test:unit" does not exist.
```

I've a similar result with `yarn` command. How can I solve this?

PS: If you need more informations, then just leave a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @vue/test-utils does not provide the `unit:test` subcommand of vue-cli-service. Those are available when using one of the following plugins:

- https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/unit-jest.html
- https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/unit-mocha.html

For instructions on how to install those see: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#installing-plugins-in-an-existing-project